# how we can get url using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have url like

`http://www.abc.com/xyz/aaa/bbb/login.php?id=23`

i want to take upto

`http://www.abc.com/xyz/aaa/bbb`

How we can do this with javascript / jquery?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one possible solution:

```
var result = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Here is another (not the best, however) solution:

```
var result = url.split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/");
```

Answer (score -2):

To get the current window URL you can use:
`window.location.href;`

Ad to extract a sub part from it till the last `/` of you can use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currUrl = window.location.href;
var modUrl =currUrl.substring(0,currUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));
//modUrl =currUrl.substring(0,currUrl.lastIndexOf("bbb"));  //Incase you have some other criteria to extract the sub URL.
</script>
```

Hope it helps.